# Cardano's Method Application

Tags: cubics

Please forgive me for any mistake in the proposal of this problem

**Problem**

> The first step of Cardano's Method states:-**Remove the term containing $x^2$ by taking $y=x-\dfrac{b}{3a}$**. However if we are not able to remove the $x^2$ in a equation then how will we solve it.

Any help is welcome. Thanks in advance

Comment: Why shouldn't you be able to remove the quadratic term?

Comment: Isn't it a contradiction in the problems description? Think about it again!

Comment: Go here $\longrightarrow$ https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~kkreith/tutorials/sample.lesson/cardano.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question doesn't make sense. If, in $ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$ (with $a\neq0$), $x$ gets replaced by $y-\frac b{3a}$ and then you expand it, you **always** get a cubic without a monomial with degree $2$, namely$$ay^3+\left(c-\frac{b^2}{3a}\right)y+\frac{2 b^3}{27 a^2}-\frac{c b}{3 a}+d.$$